# Schedule automated data export of ArcGIS Online Hosted Feature Layer to Cloud Storage (SharePoint/Google Drive)

Tags: arcgis-pro, arcgis-online, feature-layer, cloud-gis, tasks

I'm looking for a way to schedule an automated export of a hosted feature layer on ArcGIS Online to SharePoint or Google Drive.

We've attempted to use Power Automate but there's a limit of 150 features per file whilst using "Get data from Feature Layer" and ArcGIS Pro + Task Scheduler doesn't appear viable as the computer must be turned on.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: I've never used it but there are task schedulers with jupyter notebooks in AGOL: https://doc.arcgis.com/en/arcgis-online/create-maps/prepare-a-notebook-for-automated-execution.htm . The problem is you need admin level permissions.

Comment: Thanks I'll get a look. I'm an admin

Answer (score -1):

This should help get you past the 150 feature limit - https://community.esri.com/t5/arcgis-for-power-bi-blog/working-with-datasets-in-power-automate/ba-p/1126908

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).